# Can I do binding for element that is going to be created only at runtime in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I'm really asking is this:
I have array of objects inside a service, that at first load it may be empty.

```
var arr = {};
```

In one view the array is being added with objects.

```
arr[obj.id] = something;
```

Can I do binding to `{{arr[obj.id]}}` in html or code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed. Expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null in Angular JS.
Refer this link from angular https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

[image]